# Lambda expression like Sql where value or null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm coding a search for an MVC app we're building, the thing is I would like to search by various properties of an object. In this particular case this is my expected behavior:

- If both parameters are null or empty, return all.
- If any parameter has a value, select all filtered by that parameter using Contains.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var model = _svc.GetList(q => q.Name == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Name) ? q.Name : entity.Name) &&
                              q.Description ==  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Description) ? q.Description : entity.Description));
```

This returns either all elements if both fields are null or empty, or any element that matches exactly the **Name** AND/OR **Description**.

The thing here is I would like this to behave as a `Contains`.

I've managed to get this working with one field:

```
var model = _svc.GetList(q => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Name) || 
            q.Name.ToLower().Contains(entity.Name.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

But when I add the Description field, it throws a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Just to check I've tried this and it didn't work either:

```
var model = (from q in _svc.GetList()
             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(module.Name) ||
                 q.Name.ToLower().Contains(module.Name.ToLower()))
             select q).ToList();

model = (from q in model
         where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(module.Description) ||
             q.Description.ToLower().Contains(module.Description.ToLower()))
         select q).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for a multi-optional-criteria search, you can do (asserting "module" is your "search class").

Simple, and (I think) more readable. Add a null check for the description and entity property of your model.

```
//take all elements
var model = _svc.GetList();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module.Description))
  model = model.Where(m => 
                     m.Description != null && 
                     m.Description.ToLower().Contains(module.Description.ToLower());

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module.Name))
  model = model.Where(m => 
                     m.Name != null && 
                     m.Name.ToLower().Contains(module.Name.ToLower());

return module.ToList();
```

Null check, because a `ToLower()` on a null will raise a NRE !

Answer (score 1):

This is a little ugly but should do the trick, you are getting the null reference because of entries with empty `Description`. If what you are doing with the `Name` is any clue, you are probably doing something like this `q.Description.ToLower().Contains(..)` without checking that q.Description is not null

```
var model = _svc.GetList(q =>  
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Name) 
       || q.Name.ToLower().Contains(entity.Name.ToLower()))

 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity. Description) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(q. Description) 
       || q.Description.ToLower().Contains(entity. Description.ToLower())))
```